# Use computer to throw a small switch

Tags: control

Would like a product that enables me to use my computer to throw an small DC ON / OFF switch. Seems like a stupidly simple thing to do, but for the life of me I can't seem to find such a device when I search online.

Is there a device floating around out there that I can order? Or is there some kind of term I should be searching for?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you want to be able manually control the switch as well?

Comment: By  “throw a small DC ON / OFF switch” do you mean physically actuate an existing switch?

Comment: @DaemonMaker - No I don't need to manually control it.

Comment: @jwpat7 - No, not an existing switch. I just need to connect two wires carrying a low DC load for a second and then disconnect them.

Comment: How much current are we talking about?  You can use a relay or a solid state switch...  When you say switch do you mean physically disconnect?  Sometimes a transistor will do the job.

Comment: Just FYI, shopping questions are not really fit for this Q&A site. Try rephrasing the question to instead of being "what product to buy to do X?", it would be more like "how can I achieve X with properties Y, Z and W?" The answers would certainly have enough pointers for you to be able to find the product you are looking for.

Comment: There are some AC extension leads that you can control via USB. It should be easy to reuse these.

Comment: Does your computer have a parallel port? (nowadays an "old" port used for connecting printers)

Comment: It may on the motherboard. If not I could connect it to an Arduino via USB.

Comment: Put the switch in front of the computer's CD drive. Eject the CD drive, and it will hot the switch!

Answer (score 2):

There are two easy ways:

- Use a relay
- Use a transistor

In both cases, you can use the processor as the switch input...

[image: Example MOSFET switch]

Comment: I think I actually have all the parts to do this. Would you use the serial or USB port to send the signal? A concern I have is the time factor. I feel like if I can buy a USB Nerf Missile Launcher off Amazon.com, shouldn't there be a device to simply turn something on or off that is commercially available?

Comment: On a PC, you could use a parallel port directly... if you use serial or USB you will need to unpack the data first

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think I understand now, thanks so much!

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but why are you bypassing the dump load resistor with a diode?

Comment: The diode is there to stop back EMF and offers reverse protection.  The diode is (if you notice) reverse biased, so it is NOT bypassing the load!

Comment: Ok, so it allows current to flow freely from 12V to ground? When would this happen? The reason I am asking is because I built a similar, but more complex circuit to control 8 machines using the Arduino. It works fine when plugged in, but restarts the machines sometimes when I unplug the USB.

Comment: Just posted the question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85013/multiplexers-used-as-a-switch-seem-to-leak-when-power-is-cut